# Earliest gravitational map of a planet/moon?

Tags: gravity, history, measurement, geology, mapping

When was the first [gravitational map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravimetry) of a planet or moon made by measurements from space?

I'm guessing it was a map of Earth, since that's the closest planet to us,<sup>[citation needed]</sup> but for all I've been able to learn, we might have already mapped it sufficiently from the ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was the Earth, of course. As early as 1964, scientists realized that the non-Keplerian orbits satellites gave a picture of the Earth's interior. For example, see S. K. Runcorn, "Satellite gravity measurements and a laminar viscous flow model of the earth's mantle," *Journal of Geophysical Research* 69.20 (1964): 4389-4394.

Comment: Did this result in actual maps of the gravitational anomalies of Earth?